# add (Wordpress) search functionality to mmenu

Tags: wordpress, mmenu

Got the mmenu script (not the plugin) up and running on a Wordpress site. I'm trying to add search to it. I can get the search working on menu-items, but a site-search doesn't work. It looks like the script is doing a search, but it doesn't return any results. The mmenu website provides an example  (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/addons/searchfield.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my-menu").mmenu({
     navbars: {
        content: [ "searchfield" ]
     },
     searchfield: {
        search: false,
        placeholder: "Search the website"
     }
  }, {
     searchfield: {
        form: {
           name: "my-form",
           method: "post"
        },
        input: {
           name: "my-input"
        },
        submit: true
     }
  });
```

});

I don't understand the parts:

```
 form: {
            **name: "my-form",**
            method: "post"
       },
input: {
            **name: "my-input"**
       },
```

What should I fill in for "my-form" and "my-input"?

Comment: could be this. { name: "Name of your search form", method: "post" }, input: { name: "Insert here the search key" }

Comment: Thanks for your help. But where in Wordpress can I give a name to a searchform? Or where can I find the name of an existing form? And what's the searchkey?

Comment: Can you share the website you are working on? do you see any error on the console when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress You can used [wp_nav_menu_items](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/) filter to add menu item

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box_to_menu', 1, 2);
function add_search_box_to_menu( $items, $args ) { 


        $custom='<li class="Custom-menu-search"><form action="'.home_url().'" id="searchform" method="get"><input type="text"  placeholder="Search For People, News, and Stories" id="s" name="s" value="" autocomplete="off"></form></li>';
            return $custom.$items;

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It's working now, with below settings.

```
searchfield: {
        form: {
           name: "",
           method: "post"
        },
        input: {
           name: "s"
        },
        submit: true
     },
```